# Could npm link cause the cannot find module problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to learn the concept of how to use TypeScript modules from plain JavaScript projects, and it seems *to me* that I can only use a npm linked module, but not a module that npm link to others. Let me explain with an example:

```
$ cat index1.js 
const { add, multiply, divide } = require('module-a')

const newfunc = (a, b) =>
       divide(multiply(add(a, b), 6), 2);

const result = newfunc(1, 2)
console.log(result);

$ node index1.js
9
```

The `module-a` is a TypeScript module that I npm linked to from my JavaScript project. And it works fine. Now:

```
$ diff -wU 1 index1.js index2.js
--- index1.js   2019-01-01 16:25:50.000000000 -0500
+++ index2.js   2019-01-01 16:37:33.000000000 -0500
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 const { add, multiply, divide } = require('module-a')
+const { myfunc } = require('module-b')

@@ -7 +8,3 @@
 console.log(result);
+
+console.log(myfunc(1, 2));

$ node index2.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'module-b'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
...

$ ls -l node_modules/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tong tong 30 2019-01-01 16:17 module-a -> /usr/lib/node_modules/module-a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tong tong 30 2019-01-01 16:28 module-b -> /usr/lib/node_modules/module-b

$ ls -l /usr/lib/node_modules/module-b
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 83 2019-01-01 16:32 /usr/lib/node_modules/module-b -> /paths/to/ts-modules-test/module-b
```

I.e., to me `module-b` looks nothing different than `module-a`. but why it is OK to `require('module-a')` but not to `require('module-b')`?

Is it really because my `module-b` npm linked to `module-a`?

The whole npm link setup from `module-b` to `module-a`, and all the code, can be found at [this repo](https://github.com/suntong/ts-modules-test).

UPDATE. I don't have a project's package.json for either `module-a` or `module-b`, but why `module-a` works? Moreover, having created `module-c/package.json`, the problem remains the same:

```
$ find . 
.
./node_modules
./node_modules/module-a
./node_modules/module-b
./index1.js
./index2.js

$ npm init --force --yes
Wrote to /paths/to/ts-modules-test/module-c/package.json:

{
  "name": "module-c",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index1.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "module-a": "^1.0.0",
    "module-b": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

$ node index2.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'module-b'
```

Comment: Module-b needs to be in project's package.json. please share content of file.

Comment: do both `module-a` and `module-b` have a file `index.js`?

Comment: no.. `module-b` is not defined correctly. please look at "main" in `package.json` for `module-b` vs. `module-a`.    module-a defines it correctly `build/index.js` while module-b does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When nodejs requires a folder, it will try to find a main file.

By default the main file is `index.js`. Since you are using TypeScript, you do not have `index.js`, but instead you have `index.ts`.

To define a main file, you will need to define it in `package.json`. I can see you have done so in `module-a`.

```
{
   "main": "build/index.js"
}
```

This means that at some point during installation you have compiled the `ts` to `js` and the output from the compiler was placed in folder `build`.

Looking in `module-b`, your compiler for this module is also pointing to `build` folder, but the `package.json` "main" property has value "index.js". I assume that if you point it to `build/index.js` like you did in `module-a` it will work.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot Mr. Mograbi, I'm new to this and `package.json` of `module-b` was forked from somebody else's place. I would never have been able to figure this one out on my own, thanks a lot for helping!!!

Comment: This fixes my issue in Angular 10 module